# Updating Values in HTML output based on changing input

Tags: javascript, html

I currently have a set of fields and radio buttons that take in some user input. Here is an example:

```
<div id="age">
        <input type="number" name="age1" value=60>
</div>
```

I am displaying all the inputted values and want the display to change when the user modifies the input. This is my attempt:

```
    var inputElements = document.querySelectorAll('input');
    for(var i = 0, len = inputElements.length ; i < len ; i++) {
        inputElements[i].addEventListener('input', updateDisplay());
    }

     function updateDisplay () {
            console.log("test");
            var age = document.querySelector('input[name="age1"]').value;
            document.getElementById("ageComparison").innerHTML = age;
     }
```

I know that the program enters the method since the "test" message is printed to the console; however, I don't see any change in display according to changes in input. Would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While creating the eventlistener, you're just calling `updateDisplay`. Remove the `()`.
Also, you did not put '#ageComparison' element in your code.

html:

```
<div id="age">
  <input type="number" name="age1" value=60>
</div>
<div id="ageComparison">
</div>
```

js:

```
var inputElements = document.querySelectorAll('input');
for (var i = 0; i < inputElements.length; i++) {
  inputElements[i].addEventListener('input', updateDisplay);
}

function updateDisplay() {
  console.log("test");
  var age = document.querySelector('input[name=age1]').value;
  document.getElementById("ageComparison").innerHTML = age;
}
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/m6r871t6/

Answer (score 1):

Try avoiding the inner double quotes

```
   var age = document.querySelector('input[name=age1]').value;
```

try using

```
  inputElements[i].addEventListener('change', updateDisplay())
```

Comment: Thanks for your help scaisEdge. I am unable to see the effect of this. What do removing the double quotes do?

Comment: Yes and none of the output seemed to have changed.

Comment: if the test appear on console .. then the problem is in the selector or in the assignement .. (inside the selector string the inner quote are not needed )

Comment: Test does not appear on the console either, when the age input is changed.

Comment: then the problem is the listerner   try using change .. answer updated .

Comment: I've been adviced to actually use the quotes. It may fail if the attribute value contains a space, for example.